# How to get two values from the user by using SWI prolog

Tags: prolog

Im working with SWI prolog to ask the user to insert two different values according to the following codes:

```
base:-
   write('\n Please enter the base and exponent or 0 and 0 to stop the program:'),
   read   (X),
   read(Y),
   bas(X,Y).

bas(0,0):- !.
bas(X,Y):-
   f is X*Y,
   write('The power of '),write(x),
   write(' raised to '),write(y),
   write(' is '),write(f),
   base.
```

but after i do the consult the first line will display (insert The number)  but when I insert the values it show for me error.
So what is the mistake and why the program cant read my different values

Comment: upper case / lower case trouble maybe? You can't randomly change upper and lower case, they have a meaning.

Comment: I did but this error is showing for me ERROR: Stream user_input:67:71 Syntax error: Operator expected

Comment: you can't have spaces here `read   (X)`

Comment: this was a copy mistake

Answer (score 0):

here a slight reformulation

```
base :-
    writeln('enter base and exponent (terminate with .) or 0 and 0 to stop the program'),
    read(X),
    read(Y),
    bas(X,Y).

bas(0,0):- !.
bas(X,Y):-
    P is X ^ Y,
    format('The power of ~w raised to ~w is ~w~n', [X,Y,P]),
    base.
```

to me, such interaction seems a bit weird:

```
?- base.
enter base and exponent (terminate with .) or 0 and 0 to stop the program
|: 4.
|: 2.
The power of 4 raised to 2 is 16
enter base and exponent (terminate with .) or 0 and 0 to stop the program
|: 0.
|: 0.
true.
```